# How to limit axios from making more than 2 requests to the same resource at the same time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

This is how I am making the request using an axios instance. I need to know how many requests are made to a particular resource and if they are more than 2 I give a notification.

```
this.$customRequest.defaults.raxConfig = {
                retry: 2,
                retryDelay: 10000,
                backoffType: 'static',
                statusCodesToRetry: [
                    [100, 199],
                    [400, 403],
                    [405, 429]
                ],
                // This happens when retry returns errors at the end
                onRetryAttempt: err => {
                    const cfg = rax.getConfig(err);
                    if (cfg.currentRetryAttempt == 2) {
                        let informationMessage = `Cannot connect to the server.
                        Please reload the page. Contact the admin if this problem persists`;
                        this.loadToaster(informationMessage);
                    }
                }
};
const interceptorId = rax.attach(this.$customRequest);
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                this.$customRequest.get(endpoint, { params })
                    .then(res => {
                        resolve(res)
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        // Excluded status codes should load the error toaster
                        if (err.response.status === 404 || 500 <= err.response.status <= 599) {
                            let errorMessage = `The page has trouble loading. \n Try refreshing the page`;
                            this.loadToaster(errorMessage);
                        }
                    });

            })
```