# Is there a limit for concurrent requests for one axios instance?

Tags: concurrency, axios

So I am a creating an axios instance that connects to some API like this:

`const instance = axios.create(...)`

I want to know is there a limit to how many concurrent/parallel requests axios would be able to make with that singular instance. Reason for this is because I have a back-end app that receives hundreds of requests a minute and that number will only keep going up so I want to understand how the axios instance behaves under the hood to know if there is anything I need to do to avoid some sort of overload and requests getting dropped, delayed, and/or unfulfilled.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057574/how-to-limit-axios-from-making-more-than-2-requests-to-the-same-resource-at-the

Comment: @IronMan I followed the link to the post. And the post took me to a medium article, but that article doesn't answer the question of "What is the maximum amount of requests" but rather "how to set the maximum amount of allowed concurrent requests"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and reading into `axios` documentation it seems the answer is not dependent on axios itself but rather built in node features like `http` and `Agent`. If you've created an axios instance, and are you using `keep-alive:true` then `agent` will throttle and choose how it sends out requests. The answer to this stack overflow question goes more in depth on this.

[Concurrent Requests In Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060869/why-is-node-js-only-processing-six-requests-at-a-time)